# How to generate date range with variable granularity

Tags: java, date, datetime

We have some problems generating dates in the defined range. It's probably a simple task since you don't have a user defined granularity.

Example:

With `2016-02-01`, `2016-02-05` with granularity defined as `"YYYY-MM-DD"` it is obvious that the result will be `2016-02-01`, `2016-02-02`, ..., `2016-02-05` and the same with granularity `"YYYY-MM"`.

But we don't know which granularity will be chosen, so we must consider all datetime patterns allowed by definition in the manual.

Is there some way to simply increment by the smallest date unit specified in date format? FE. `"YYYY-MM-DD"` it is obvious, that it's one day.

The only solution, that I could think of, is to add one millisecond to a date, format it to granularity and check if the string repr. of the date changed. But it's completely unthinkable because of it's astronomical inefficiency.

Thanks in advance,

Michal

Comment: Instead of defining the date range with start, end and format, why don't you define it with start, end and increment unit?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about it, but i'm afraid that it won't help if you want increment by months, which are of different count of days.

Comment: If using a text format such as "yyyy-mm-dd" for the granularity is not required, there are certainly better options. You could for example pass an "incrementing algorithm".

Comment: @MichalLičko and why couldn't you pass the unit MONTH as granularity, and increment by month?

Comment: @JBNizet it's because we don't have finite enumeration of all possible granularities. It could be anything like week, days of week, years or even seconds or milis.

Comment: @assylias Passing an incrementing function such as an lambda in java8 would be really nice solution, but the method we are talking about is an XML-RPC server method which should serve some external requests. I'm afraid that XML-RPC won't be able to provide such a functionality as method passing.